# How to simulate time increase in Remix IDE?

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, truffle-test, unittesting

#### In my JavaScript tests:

```
module.exports = {
    increaseTime: (duration) => {
      const id = Date.now();
    
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        web3.currentProvider.send({
          jsonrpc: '2.0',
          method: 'evm_increaseTime',
          params: [duration],
          id: id,
        }, err1 => {
          if (err1) return reject(err1);
    
          web3.currentProvider.send({
            jsonrpc: '2.0',
            method: 'evm_mine',
            id: id + 1,
          }, (err2, res) => {
            return err2 ? reject(err2) : resolve(res);
          });
        });
      });
    },

}
```

#### In the Remix IDE?

I'm doing some manual debugging and I really wish I knew how to fast-forward the time?